# How can I read request values received with Python?

Tags: python, request

I want to make a simple python script to be run in my server. What it's supposed to do is receive requests and return values according to requests it received.

I want to access the script with a way like `http://example.com/thescript.py?first=3&second=4`.
and make the script to read the `first` and `second` and to do jobs with the values.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use [`Flask`](http://flask.pocoo.org/):

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    first = request.args.get('first')
    second = request.args.get('second')
    return render_template('index.html', first=first, second=second)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

And the template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
First: {{ first }}
<br />
Second: {{ second }}
</body>
</html>
```

This code will simply print the two parameters provided.